# express stops me changing request.path?

Tags: node.js, url, express, middleware

I am writing an [express](/questions/tagged/express) app, and wanted to create a middleware that standardises incoming urls to a certain "expected" format, it should convert a path like `/Docs/PAGE/` to `/docs/page`.

I would like to do this to make path-handling middleware easier to write later on.

Here is what I wrote:

```
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
  var standardisedPath = request.path.toLowerCase().replace(/\/$/, '');
  logger.info('Standardising original path %s to %s', request.path, standardisedPath);
  request.path = standardisedPath;
  next();
});

app.get(/^\/docs.*/i, function(request, response) {
  var docPath = request.path + '.md';
  response.send(docPath);
});
```

However, when I visit `http://localhost/docs/PAGE/` for example, my app responds with `/docs/PAGE/.md`, even though I'm expecting `/docs/page.md`.

Comment: `standardisedPath` and `normalisedPath` can be the same variable...

Comment: @sova I forgot to find/replace the whole file by this point.

Comment: Setting `request.path` throws an exception for me. Besides that, it sounds to me like you want to generate a redirect, if you want the URL in the browser to show the lowercase version.

Comment: @robertklep that does in fact sound a better solution, is there a way I can reditrect to the correct URLs? I would accept an answer showing this.

Answer (score 1):

Say that you want to redirect any URL's which have at least one upper case character in their path to the lower cased equivalent:

```
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
  if (/[A-Z]/.test(request.url)) { // check for at least one upper case character
    return response.redirect(request.url.toLowerCase());
  }
  next();
});
```